# JSON Serializer malforming C# model to JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

I'm trying to post a C# Model to an API by serializing to JSON. The issue I'm having, for reasons unknown, is that it is combining values together? Below is a snippet of the JSON where it has malformed.

```
"noOfYearsInsured"…esidencyMonths":"60"
```

I've tried implementing both the C# System.Text.Json Serializer and the Newtonsoft.Json serializer, but one malforms the model elsewhere, and the other in a completely unrelated place?

Is there any JsonSerializerSettings that can be applied to this that could solve the issue?

Comment: Post the code where you are “serializing to JSON”.

Comment: You have to post the whole json and show how it is could be mallformed, just extra double quotes or something else too?